# How to include class from css module to the react-transition-group component?

Tags: react-transition-group

I'm using react-transition-group library and for styling css module.scss,
How correctly pass classes to the  component?

Now I commented .module.scss,
and instead it  using simple .scss file

```
import './SideDrawer.style.scss';
// import style from './index.module.scss';

const NavBar = ({ showSideDrawer, currentUser }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <CSSTransition
        in={showSideDrawer}
        timeout={300}
        // classNames={{ ...style }}
        classNames="menu"
        unmountOnExit
      >
        <SideDrawer currentUser={currentUser} />
      </CSSTransition>

    </div>
  );
};
```

How correctly to set classNames in the  component?